# Looking for a recommendation to use WebService in communication

Tags: c#, web-services, communication

i have PC that connect to my WebService on the server.

what are the best recommendation to use and check if i have connection ?

if there isn't connection:

1. to make loop for 5 times and check again ?
2. or to make longer the time out connection ?
3. or to send messageBox "try again" ?

what is the best thing to do ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about winforms applications, I'll probably try a DNS lookup for a public address, a discrete button for manual retries and a Thread.Sleep to automatic checks.

If that DNS lookup works, it's time to try that web service call.

EDIT: seems possible to do a P/invoke call to check for internet connection, as described in [Check Your Internet Connection With C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/check-your-internet-connection-with-c/)

Comment: Not totally sure about this, but don't DNS lookups get cached for a little while by the OS network stack? So I'm not sure that would be a 100% reliable way to test connectivity.

Comment: @axel_c, interesting argument! If we can't avoid that DNS caching, maybe we should to call that webservice with a small timeout.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what your users expect and do you expect to be the reason for the failure.

If the command you're sending to the server is some sort of periodic check, you can just try next time, and maybe write some message in the status bar.

If the most likely case is that the connection is down on the user's PC, just show a error message, retrying won't help you.

If the problem is something like overloaded server, trying again few times might be the best solution.